# Audio controls in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, html, audio, cross-browser, audio-streaming

I need to give users option to play audio files, with extensive controls for seeking, skipping, jump to time etc. etc.

I obviously prefer the file should be streamed so it starts playing while still downloading.

I also prefer not to use a plug-in if that is an option, the application should be as browser-compatible as possible.

Comment: what is your target supporting browsers ?

Comment: Worldwide major browsers, Chrome, IE, FF etc.

Comment: and version ? you should know that IE6 and IE9 is very different.

Comment: @ShivanRaptor I think I am first looking for browsers who support HTML5, those stupid users who refuse to update their browsers won't access my product anyway.

Comment: This question is very broad, and doesn't really have a specific answer.  The best you're going to get is a list of recommendations based on people's opinions (which is not the purpose of Stack Overflow, per the FAQ section on what not to ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay simply you could use the audio tag:

```
  <audio>
  <source src="Foo.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />
  <source src="Foo.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
  Your Browser don't support the audio tag
  </audio>
```

You could use the default Controls or create your own custom progress bar and play , stop button
See this link for more help Audio Same Concept as video
http://thenewboston.org/watch.php?cat=43&number=27
And
http://thenewboston.org/watch.php?cat=43&number=28